# Facebook .net return internal server error when using Multiquery

Tags: .net, facebook, fql.multiquery

Hello I am having trouble using multiquery in facebook .net.

I am trying to create 3 queries: Friends, Like and Photo using multiquery in the toolkit. It returns me with this The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. Although, it is not happened all the time but it does occur frequently... I thought about what cause the problem but don't have a luck

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try update your core Facebook API Kit with the latest version, Internal Error 500 is more than likly one of the following:

Facebook's Rest server is experiencing issues with server load.
Your requests are invalid, thus the need to update your library.

If the above does not resolve the situation try ask in the Facebook Developers Forum.